# How to delete bad saved files from external disk?

Tags: external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I have a external USB hard disk (Seagate if matters) of 1TB with 350GB of free space. I copied aprox 270 GB from computer to external disk. All looked fine, the free space then was aprox 70GB and data copied was there.

Then after finish the copy I restarted computer and when I saw again the external disk, all information I'd just copied wasn´t there but the external disk free space remains in 70GB, but I cannot see the folders I copied.

I scan the disk with Windows 10 built in tool and found errors and Windows detects that disk has only 600GB of total size(actually is 1TB). Then a scan with a free tool named Easus Recovery that tool shows the correct disk size (1TB) and shows the folders I copied.

My question is how can I deleted those 270GB of data I copied(that seems to have error) to recover those 270GB of free space on disk? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: By far the quickest way is to fast reformat the drive, if you don't have other data on it. Even copying off the valid data to another disk, and then formatting, is still likely the fastest option.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Currently I don´t have enough space on computer to copy the valid data to format disk, due to that I'm trying to find a way to recover the lost space, if possible.